# PHP - preg_replace and UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

I'm currently retrieving data from my database. I receive an array that contains a 'title' index with an UTF8 encoded value. What I'd like is to use this value as the name of the file in which something will be saved, so I'm doing this:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Where $filename is

```
'-' . $category['root'] . '-articles-' . $category['id'] . '-' . $this->Urlize($category['category'])
```

Here is the code of "Urlize" :

```
private function Urlize($value)
{
    if ($value != null && trim($value) != '')
    {
        $value = preg_replace('/([\[\(].*[\]\)])/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[\s]/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[,!?.;:\"\'&+\/]/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[-]+/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/(^-)/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/-$/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[éèê]/i', 'e', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[âà]/i', 'a', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[öô]/i', 'o', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[ûùü]/i', 'u', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[îïíì]/i', 'i', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[#]/i', 'sharp', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[<>]/i', '-', $value);

        if ($value[strlen($value) - 1] == '-')
        {
            $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 1);
        }
    }

    return strtolower($value);
}
```

My issue is that for the title "Théorie générale", I get "theeorie-geeneerale", so "e" are doubled. I guess it is something related to the charset by I cannot find a good way to avoid it. Of course, I'd like to have "theorie-generale".

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the unicode modifier, `u`, when using unicode in the regex.

So try:

```
function Urlize($value) {
    if ($value != null && trim($value) != '')
    {
        $value = preg_replace('/([\[\(].*[\]\)])/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[\s]/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[,!?.;:\"\'&+\/]/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[-]+/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/(^-)/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/-$/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[éèê]/iu', 'e', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[âà]/iu', 'a', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[öô]/iu', 'o', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[ûùü]/ui', 'u', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[îïíì]/ui', 'i', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[#]/i', 'sharp', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[<>]/i', '-', $value);

        if ($value[strlen($value) - 1] == '-')
        {
            $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 1);
        }
    }
    return strtolower($value);
}
echo Urlize('Théorie générale');
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b7e5985dc23ac71a6298783d2dad646d875d3c8

Output:

> theorie-generale

You could use the `|` (or) grouping to reduce the number of preg_replace's you have. It might make your regexs a bit harder to read though. You could also use arrays for the finds and replaces. Here's the first approach.

```
function Urlize($value) {
    if ($value != null && trim($value) != '')
    {
        $value = preg_replace('/(([\[\(].*[\]\)])|(^-)|-$)/i', '', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/([,!?.;:\"\'&+\/]|[\s]|[-]+|[<>])/i', '-', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[éèê]/iu', 'e', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[âà]/iu', 'a', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[öô]/iu', 'o', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[ûùü]/ui', 'u', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[îïíì]/ui', 'i', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/[#]/i', 'sharp', $value);
        if ($value[strlen($value) - 1] == '-') {
            $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 1);
        }
    }
    return strtolower($value);
}
echo Urlize('Théorie générale');
```